# Ubuntu Server 21.10 - How to run Shell Script when plugging USB device

Tags: shell, ubuntu, usb, udev

I would like to run a specific script when plugging a USB device. But, nothing happens when I a USB device.

Here is the script I would like to run ( `/home/update.sh` ):

```
#!/bin/sh
netplan apply
```

In the same directory, I made it executable by running:

```
sudo chmod +x update.sh
```

I updated the udev rule file ( `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-snap.snapd.rules` ) by adding the following line after `LABEL="mm_mbm_check"` :

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="`****`", ATTRS{idProduct}=="`****`", RUN+="/home/update.sh"
```

As far as I understand, I'm using the * to allow any usb device.

After updating this udev rule file, I run the following script to apply the rules:

```
sudo service udev restart
```

Here is the log from syslog after running the restart udev command ( `tail -f /var/log/syslog` ):

```
Nov  8 19:52:20 ubuntu systemd-udevd[23328]: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pi-bluetooth.rules:14 Invalid value "/bin/sh -c 'ALIASES=/proc/device-tree/aliases; if cmp -s $ALIASES/uart0 $ALIASES/serial0; then echo 0;elif cmp -s $ALIASES/uart0 $ALIASES/serial1; then echo 1; else exit 1; fi'" for PROGRAM (char 58: invalid substitution type), ignoring, but please fix it.
Nov  8 19:52:20 ubuntu systemd-udevd[23328]: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pi-bluetooth.rules:27 Invalid value "/bin/sh -c 'ALIASES=/proc/device-tree/aliases; if [ -e /dev/ttyAMA0 ]; then exit 1; elif cmp -s $ALIASES/uart0 $ALIASES/serial0; then echo 0;elif cmp -s $ALIASES/uart0 $ALIASES/serial1; then echo 1; else exit 1; fi'" for PROGRAM (char 97: invalid substitution type), ignoring, but please fix it.
Nov  8 19:52:20 ubuntu systemd-udevd[23328]: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pi-bluetooth.rules:38 Invalid value "/bin/sh -c 'ALIASES=/proc/device-tree/aliases; if cmp -s $ALIASES/uart1 $ALIASES/serial0; then echo 0; elif cmp -s $ALIASES/uart1 $ALIASES/serial1; then echo 1; else exit 1; fi '" for PROGRAM (char 58: invalid substitution type), ignoring, but please fix it.
```

Finally, when I plug the USB device to the Raspberry, nothing happens.

My configuration:

- Raspberry Pi 3
- Ubuntu Server 21.10

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct, except the added rule in the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-snap.snapd.rules` .

To make it works, I added a new file `90-usb.rules` in the `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory including the following rule:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="****", ATTRS{idProduct}=="****", RUN+="/home/update.sh"
```

instead of

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="`****`", ATTRS{idProduct}=="`****`", RUN+="/home/update.sh"
```

I restarted the udev using the following script:

```
sudo service udev restart
```

And now, when I'm plugging any USB device, my script is running.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've found for using the contents of a mounted USB key

1. Add a script that will be launched when the USB flash drive is plugged in:

`nano /home/user/usbhook.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Debugging test script called by udev

# File paths, to be customized as needed
logFile="/tmp/logFileUsbHook.txt"
dateFile="/tmp/.logDateUsbHook.date"

# Ensure only one instance is running at a time
instances=$(lsof -t "$0" | wc -l)
if (( $instances > 1 )); then exit 1; fi

# Prevent multiple executions inside a 3-second time frame
if [ ! -f $dateFile ]; then
    echo "lastExecution=0" > $dateFile
fi
source $dateFile # reads the $lastExecution var from file
timeframe=$(( $(date +%s) - $lastExecution )) # seconds from last execution
if (( $timeframe <= 3 )); then exit 1; fi
echo "lastExecution=$(date +%s)" > $dateFile

# Debugging info
echo "USB Device '$1' plugged in..." >> $logFile

sleep 5

# Retrieve the mount point of the USB device based on the device name
device_name="$1"
usb_mount_point=$(grep "$device_name" /etc/mtab | awk '{print $2}')

# Check if the USB device is mounted
if [ -n "$usb_mount_point" ]; then
    # Access the directory of the USB device
    cd "$usb_mount_point"
    echo "USB device directory: $usb_mount_point" >> $logFile
     # Do stuff with the content of your usb key
else
    echo "No mount point found for the device $device_name." >> $logFile
fi

# Do other stuff...
exit 0
```

Dont't forget to add execution with :
`chmod +x /home/user/usbhook.sh`

2. Add an udev rule to trigger usb key connection :

`sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usbhook.rules`

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="dummy@%k.service"
```

Reload rules:

`sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`

3. Add service:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/dummy@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Run script on USB plug

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/simon/usbhook.sh %i
RemainAfterExit=no
```

Reload services:

`systemctl daemon-reload`